# Populating fields in an ASP.Net DetailsView when "New" button is clicked from DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, code-behind, populate, findcontrol

Using an ASP.Net DetailsView with VB.Net in a code-behind file, we would like to make it easier for the user to do data entry when they are inserting data.

We would like to implement a way for the DetailsView to remember the value in particular fields prior to clicking the "New" button. After it remembers the values we would like to populate 2 of the fields which are a DropDownList and a TextBox field with the remembered values after clicking "New".

Currently we tried this in the code-behind file:

```
Protected Sub DetailsViewDetails_ItemCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewCommandEventArgs)

    Select Case e.CommandName

        Case "Add"

        Case "Edit"
            ButtonAddNewAttendance.Enabled = False

        Case "Delete"

        Case "Update"
            ButtonAddNewAttendance.Enabled = True

        Case "Insert"

        Case "New"
            Dim txtBox As New TextBox
            txtBox = DetailsView.FindControl("TextBoxDateAttendanceTakenInsert")
            txtBox.Text = DateTime.Now

            Dim drpValue As DropDownList
            drpValue = DetailsView.FindControl("DropDownListClassInsert")
            drpValue.SelectedValue = 1
    End Select
End Sub
```

When the "New" button is clicked this error is displayed:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This error is on txtBox.Text = DateTime.Now

It's almost as if it can't find the field from the markup. Can you tell me what else I need to add to the coding?

If I comment out the coding for the TextBox and leave the coding to run for the DropDownList it produces the same error.

Here is the markup showing 2 of the fields:

```
<asp:DetailsView 
    ID="DetailsView" 
    runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateRows="False" 
    Height="50px" 
    Width="207px" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDetails"
    DataKeyNames="ID"
    OnItemCommand="DetailsViewDetails_ItemCommand">

<Fields>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Class:" SortExpression="ClassID">
    <EditItemTemplate>

        <asp:DropDownList 
            ID="DropDownListClassEdit" 
            Runat="server"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceClasses"
            DataTextField = "ClassName"
            DataValueField="ID"
            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ClassID") %>'
            ForeColor="Blue">
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorEditClass" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownListClassEdit" 
             ErrorMessage="Please select a Class here." Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red" 
             SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic">

         </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

     </EditItemTemplate>

     <InsertItemTemplate>

         <asp:DropDownList 
             ID="DropDownListClassInsert" 
             Runat="server"
             DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceClasses"
             DataTextField = "ClassName"
             DataValueField="ID"
             SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ClassID") %>'
             AppendDataBoundItems="True"
             ForeColor="Blue">
         </asp:DropDownList>

         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorInsertClass" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownListClassInsert" 
             ErrorMessage="Please select a Class here." Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red" 
             SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic">

         </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
     </InsertItemTemplate>

     <ItemTemplate>

         <asp:DropDownList 
             ID="DropDownListClass" 
             Runat="server"
             DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceClasses"
             DataTextField = "ClassName"
             DataValueField="ID"
             SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ClassID") %>'
             Enabled="false"
             ForeColor="Blue"
             Font-Bold="true"> 
         </asp:DropDownList>

     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField 
     HeaderText="Attendance Date:" SortExpression="DateAttendanceTaken">
     <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox 
             ID="TextBoxDateAttendanceTakenEdit" 
             runat="server" 
             Text='<%# Bind("DateAttendanceTaken", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'>
         </asp:TextBox>
     </EditItemTemplate>

     <InsertItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox 
             ID="TextBoxDateAttendanceTakenInsert" 
             runat="server" 
             Text='<%# Bind("DateAttendanceTaken", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'>
         </asp:TextBox>
     </InsertItemTemplate>

     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label 
             ID="LabelDateAttendanceTaken" 
             runat="server" 
             Text='<%# Bind("DateAttendanceTaken", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'>
         </asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>

     <ItemStyle ForeColor="Blue" />
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

For now I hard coded a value into:

```
drpValue.SelectedValue = 1
```

until we can get the coding to work.

*** UPDATE ***

ItemCommand is not the correct place to put the coding.

I found out that to get this to work, OnDataBinding needs to be added as shown here plus making sure there is a handler in the code-behind file as shown below.

InsertItemTemplate markup:

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList 
        ID="DropDownListClassInsert" 
        Runat="server"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceClasses"
        DataTextField = "ClassName"
        DataValueField="ID"
        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ClassID") %>'
        AppendDataBoundItems="True"
        ForeColor="Blue"
        OnDataBinding="DropDownListClassInsert_DataBinding">
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorInsertClass" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownListClassInsert" 
        ErrorMessage="Please select a Class here." Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red" 
        SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

Handler in the code-behind file:

```
Protected Sub DropDownListClassInsert_DataBinding(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim drpValue As DropDownList
    drpValue = DetailsView.FindControl("DropDownListClassInsert")
    drpValue.SelectedValue = intCurrentClassID
End Sub
```

Note: intCurrentClassID is declared as:

```
Public Shared intCurrentClassID As Integer = Nothing
```

after:

```
Public Class
```

I hope this helps others who had the same issues.

Comment: Try this: if you look for DropDownListClassEdit instead of DropDownListClassInsert, is the control found? If so, you need to take the Details View out of Edit mode. My VB is rusty, but it's probably something like e.EditIndex = -1

Comment: Thanks Melanie for the reply. Using DropDownListClassEdit still produced the same error.

Comment: What is the ID of your DetailsView? If it's not DetailsView, then you need to use that with your FindControl statement

Comment: The DetailsView is also called: ID="DetailsView" Can you show me the correct syntax to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you comment out the RequiredFieldValidator and see what happens? In other words, just have one control in the InsertItemTemplate. I'm curious if your code will find the DropDownList then. If so, you may have to loop through all the controls in the InsertItemTemplate, but before we go there, please try commenting out the validator and testing

Comment: Same error occurs when the RequiredFieldValidator is removed.